# OpenID implementation like StackOverFlow

Tags: openid, openid-provider

I'm looking to implement OpenID the same way that StackOverFlow uses it.  I've looked through a few APIs and I've scouted out [JanRain](http://www.janrain.com/) but I'm not sure these do what I'm looking for.  Has anyone duplicated the login functionality available here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with http://simpleid.sourceforge.net

Comment: That download contains about 80 files, is it really that complicated?

Answer (score 1):

http://openid.net/add-openid/

Thats the link to adding the OpenID StackOverFlow uses.  They have plug ins for:

- Drupal
- Wordpress (OpenID)
- Wordpress (Janrain Engage)
- SPIP
- WebGUI
- MediaWiki
- DokuWiki
- phpBB
- PunBB

Janrain Engage, what you talked about in your question, is a hosted solution that adds OpenID to websites with very light engineering requirements.

Comment: That link is where I was, it provides a few PHP API (I need custom integration) but I was wondering if anyone had used those APIs.